# Из PHP массива в двухуровневый SELECT

Tags: javascript, select

есть массив вида [0]=>["name" => "cat_name", "id" => "cat_id", "child_cat" => ["child_name" => "child_cat_name", "child_id" => "child_cat_id"]....],[1]=>["name" => "cat_name", "id" => "cat_id", "child_cat" => ["child_name" => "child_cat_name", "child_id" => "child_cat_id"]....].....

Нужно данный массив перевести в select в первом поле которого будут выпадать главные категории, а при клике во втором select выпадали подкатегории.

Подскажите куда копать!

Comment: ну, надо по идее руками перевести массив в список ul li а потом можно использовать какой-нибудь `jquery.accordion` например

Comment: А пример реализации можно какой нибуть?

Comment: как подключить плагин можно тут посмотреть https://webformyself.com/ispolzovanie-vidzheta-akkordeon-dlya-menyu/. У вас сложности с подключением или с преобразованием массива в списки ul li?

Comment: Сделать один select с категориями и на каждую подкатегорию по своему select. Потом сделать display:none для всех селектов подкатегорий и при выборе категории показывать нужный селект (JS|JQuery)